# Rank 4 Variables From Highest To Lowest

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this python 3 code:

```
countA=0
countB=0
countC=0
countD=0
for a in range(min(len(String1), len(String2))):
      if String1[a] == String2[a] == 'A':
          countA += 1
      elif String1[a] == String2[a] == 'B':
          countB += 1
      elif String1[a] == String2[a] == 'C':
          countC += 1
      elif String1[a] == String2[a] == 'D':
          countD += 1
```

it's output is (when i print each count)
    222
    444
    111
    555

Expected Output (From Highest To Lowest)
    555
    444
    222
    111

Any Ideas on how to do it
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```py
l = [222, 444, 111, 555]
l.sort()
l.reverse()
print(l)
```

The output will be:

```
[555, 444, 222, 111]
```

Read up about the [sort](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) function, and the [reverse](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/list_reverse.htm) function.

Hopefully this helps!
Hopefully this helps!

Comment: @jana What do you mean?